# Is there any NHibernate equivalent of the sql 'left' function?

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

Currently the project needs to retrieve massive data from the sql server database, so is there any equivalent of the sql 'left' function in NHibernate which can function like below to get less content property data from the database?

```
SELECT
    m.*, left(mc.Content, 30) as Content
from
    Message m
INNER JOIN
    MessageContent mc
ON
    m.SequenceID = mc.SequenceID
```

"string.substring()" is not suitable here because really massive data here, applying "left" function is aiming to cut the retrieving time from the database.

Comment: Use an actual SQL query.  See https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, am investigating into it.

Answer (score 0):

The left() function is available in HQL.

I think if you use string.Substring() in the select clause of LINQ query NHibernate might be able to pass this method call into the SQL statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing. I finally just created an actual SQL query which also increase the operating speed.

Comment: @pri17 You claim about the performance sounds a bit suspiscious... unless you were projected to mapped entities with HQL/LINQ but just to non-mapped DTO:s with the SQL query? I would imagine that a LINQ query would be translated to effectively the same SQL and be just as performant.

Comment: Well, no matter for what "theories" should perform the same, but in reality, actual SQL query do perform a way better